# How to split a 1-D tensor by a certain index tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

There's a 1-D tensor of int32. I'd like to replace the elements before the first appearing 1 with 0.

```
#This is a numpy equivalent.
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 5], np.int32)
first_ind = np.where(a == 1)[0][0] # => 2
result = np.concatenate((np.zeros((first_ind,)), a[first_ind:]))
# =>[ 0.  0.  1.  3.  1.  2.  3.  3.  1.  5.]

import tensorflow as tf
_a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
_first_ind = tf.where(tf.equal(_a, 1))[0][0]
# But I don't know what to do next.
```

Answer (score 1):

I myself got the answer.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 5], np.int32)
first_ind = np.where(a == 1)[0][0] # => 2
result = np.concatenate((np.zeros((first_ind,)), a[first_ind:]))
# =>[ 0.  0.  1.  3.  1.  2.  3.  3.  1.  5.]

import tensorflow as tf
_a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
_first_ind = tf.where(tf.equal(_a, 1))[0]

zero_padding = tf.zeros(tf.to_int32(_first_ind), tf.int32)
_a_back = tf.slice(_a, _first_ind, [-1])
out = tf.concat(0, (zero_padding, _a_back))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print out.eval()
    #=> [0 0 1 3 1 2 3 3 1 5]
```